# Using "Case" in SOQL Select statement

Tags: soql

Trying to use Case in SOQL's select. SOQL doesn't like that one bit! Any ideas what's the equivalent of Case?

My code should be something like:
SELECT Client_Account__c,

**CASE Max(Termination_Date__c) <= TODAY**

**THEN Termination_Date__c**

**ELSE 'Active'**

FROM Plan__c

GROUP BY Client_Account__c

LIMIT 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in SOQL. More to the point, you'll need some code. You'd have to query all rows, then determine which one you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a formula field with an equivalent CASE statement in it, and then query that formula field using SOQL - which would give you the same result without writing any Apex.

Comment: Thank you, for our uses I can just pull the date alone.. I was just trying to go the extra mile :)