# Join two different picklists on value

Tags: soql, case, picklist, outer-join

I want to join two picklists on Value (Country) to have a result like below because I noticed that for some Markets one of the picklist values is missing either IsoCode2 (`Aruba`) or IsoCode3 (`Bonaire`).

| Iso2 | Label | Iso3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Aruba | ABW |
| AU | Australia | AUS |
| BE | Belgium | BEL |
| BQ | Bonaire |  |
| DK | Denmark | DNK |

The two picklists are for [country iso codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) for the same object `Market__c`:

- `IsoCode2` for country codes with two digits (`AU`, `BE`, `DK`, `US`)
- `IsoCode3` for country codes with two digits (`AUS`, `BEL`, `DNK`, `USA`)

I have a query to get the values of this picklist

```
SELECT Value, Label
FROM PicklistValueInfo 
WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Market__c' 
      AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName = 'IsoCode2__c'
```

Or query both at the same time

```
SELECT Value, Label, IsActive
FROM PicklistValueInfo
WHERE
EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'MarketProfile__c'
AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName
    in ('Country3Digit__c', 'CountryISOCode2__c')
ORDER BY Label
```

Which returns

| Value | Label |
| --- | --- |
| ABW | Aruba |
| AU | Australia |
| AUS | Australia |
| BE | Belgium |
| BEL | Belgium |

It seems that case

- `Case WHEN Len(Value) = 2 AS 'Iso2'` and
- `Case WHEN Len(Value) = 3 AS 'Iso3'`

is not supported (see [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4OjWSAV) or [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64384/using-case-in-soql-select-statement))

#### Question

How to create a join be used to get a result like the first table?

Comment: You may not be able to do this with a single query.  You might have to use a wrapper object and do separate queries to build your list.